# Select tag not working properly with Anuglar

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm building a form using Angular.
in my form, there is a type of select as a tag.

Below is my code:

```
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form['{{field.id}}'].$invalid }" ng-if="field.type === 'select'">
            <select>
                    <div class="" ng-repeat="value in field.values">
                        <option value="">{{value.title}}</option>
                    </div>
            </select>
        </div>
```

And here is json file for field.values:

```
 "values": [
                                {
                                    "id": 0,
                                    "title": "Not Selected"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "title": "Yes"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 2,
                                    "title": "No"
                                }
                            ]
```

Javascript(changes made):

app.controller('I129Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'JSONModelsService',
    function ($scope, $http, JSONModelsService) {

```
    var formData = {};

    $scope.groups = [];
    $scope.sections = [];
    $scope.fields = [];

    //below is basically equivalent to routing
    JSONModelsService.get(['test', 'Valid Passport'])
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            // $scope.group = response.data.groups[0];
            $scope.groups = response.data.groups;
            $scope.sections = $scope.groups.sections;
            $scope.fields = $scope.groups.sections.fields;
        });
```

Basically, I first check whether `field.type` is equal to `select`. If so, I want to values in select type of question. However, it is not working as I imagine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure Json you posted is correct or you just posted a part of Json . i see a mistake in JSON it self

Comment: do change `ng-class` to `ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form[field.id].$invalid }"`, I don't think so that would fix entire issue. could you add more explanation with `plunkr/fiddle`

Comment: I have a valid json but it is too long to fit here. so I just put part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First don't use a div element in a select this can't work. You can put ng-repeat in option level but this won't work since you don't have ng-model binded with this.

The way of doing it is the directive ng-options in select tag.

```
<select ng-model="valueSelected" ng-options="value as value.title for value in field.values"></select>
```

If you want to let your user being able to not select/unselect a value. Add in the select the following option :

```
<option ng-value="null">-- No value--</option>
```

Comment: Is this (ng-repeat="value as value.title in field.values") supposed to work? I do not see anything.

Comment: no as i isaid it's ng-options i just put ng-repeat in my select instead of ng-options. I edited my post, sorry for that.

Comment: even if i change to ng-options, it still does not show anything. it has a select type of form but empty

Comment: show us your controller please.  If you loop over fields.values you should have the following in your code : $scope.field = {}; [..] $scope.field.values = values;

Comment: I have     $scope.groups = response.data.groups;
    $scope.sections = $scope.group.sections;

Comment: then do ng-options="section as section.title in sections". Of course change the section.title by what fit in your data. If this doesn't work show us your javascript.

Comment: Yeah. no luck. Added javascript file. JSONService is merely a function to read a jsonfile.

Comment: You have a typo there   $scope.sections = $scope.group.sections; you forget the 's' to 'groups'

Comment: Same here :   $scope.group = {}; -> $scope.groups = []; i guess

Comment: I did make all changes as you said but it somehow still is missing the data. hmm..

Comment: can you set a plunkr ? In order to have something really near of what you have just change the implementation of your service by a manual promise using $q.defer.

Comment: I just noticed i made a typoe, the right text in ng-options is value as value.title for value in field.values

Comment: It works! haha. Typo always causes a problem :) Thank you so much for checking this problem out!!